# JPA autogenerate id from a starting point without creating that separate id table

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

In JPA I want to autogenerate an integer primary key where the generation should start from, say, 1000. I'm new to JPA and I have used IDENTITY type earlier to avoid those extra id tables that JPA otherwise generates. I've tried using SEQUENCE but it generates a seperate id table as well.

Earlier code:

```
@Id
@Column(length = 4)
@GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer reservationId;
```

For what I can see, you can't get IDENTITY to increment from a specified starting point.

Is there any way I can use JPA to increment from a starting point and not get extra id tables?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @MauricioBuffon MySQL

Comment: Ok, I had a similar issue in the past. If I remember correctly, it happened because the database didn't accept identity columns. But this is not the case with MySQL. My suggestion is to specify the dialect for the persistence provider. If you are using Hibernate, this is done by adding `<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />` on `persistence.xml` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert in MySQL, but searching the web it seems that MySQL doesn't support sequences - at least, stricto sensu. So either you use `GenerationType.IDENTITY` or `GenerationType.TABLE`.

In order to prove the concept, let's code a little. In the following examples, I will show the entity class, its metadata, and the SQL the persistence provider generated based on them.

### GenerationType.IDENTITY

The entity class:

```java
@Entity
public class EntityOne {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
}
```

The generated SQL:

```sql
create table EntityOne (id integer not null auto_increment, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB;
```

If you need to start the `AUTO_INCREMENT` column from a specific value, as per the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html), a possible solution is to insert a row with that value and then delete it.

### GenerationType.SEQUENCE

The entity class:

```java
@Entity
public class EntityTwo {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "EntityTwoSequence", initialValue = 1000)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "EntityTwoSequence")
    private Integer id;
}
```

The generated SQL:

```sql
create table EntityTwo (id integer not null, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB;
create table EntityTwoSequence (next_val bigint) engine=InnoDB;
insert into EntityTwoSequence values ( 1000 );
```

Again, this is because MySQL does not support sequences. If the database used were one that supports sequences, a sequence creation would be seen above.

### GenerationType.TABLE

The entity class:

```java
@Entity
@TableGenerator(name = "MySequenceGenerator")
public class EntityThree {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "MySequenceGenerator")
    private Integer id;
}
```

The generated SQL:

```sql
create table EntityThree (id integer not null, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB;
create table MySequenceGenerator (sequence_name varchar(255) not null, next_val bigint, primary key (sequence_name)) engine=InnoDB;
insert into MySequenceGenerator(sequence_name, next_val) values ('EntityThree',0);
```

It looks like the difference between `@SequenceGenerator` and `@TableGenerator` in MySQL is that `@TableGenerator` creates only one table with multiple rows to manage all the ids that reference it (the expected behavior, by the way), while `@SequenceGenerator` creates a table for each annotation.

### GenerationType.UUID

I decided - why not?, to see what happens when using the UUID generation type.

The entity class:

```java
@Entity
public class EntityFour {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID id;
}
```

The generated SQL:

```sql
create table EntityFour (id binary(16) not null, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB;
```

Only the table is created. This suggests that the id generation, in this case, is managed by the persistence provider - which is actually what the [specification says](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.1/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.1.html#a14790).

### IMPORTANT

1. I suggest you to set the dialect property of your persistence provider. Normally, this is done in the `persistence.xml` file. If you are using Hibernate, you should add the following line:

```xml
<persistence ...>
    ...
    <persistence-unit ...>
        ...
        <properties>
            ...
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

2. To enable the SQL script schema generation, you have to set in `persistence.xml` file the properties `jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action` and `jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target`.
3. Note that the `next_val` columns are defined as `bigint`. So, if you are going to use a sequence or table generator, I suggest you to set the entity id field as a Long.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_gen_name")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_gen_name", sequenceName = "my_sequence", initialValue = 1000, allocationSize = 1)
```

In this example name is the name of the sequence generator,
sequenceName is the name of the database sequence to use,
initialValue is the initial value of the sequence and
allocationSize is the increment size of the sequence.

Note: The SEQUENCE strategy requires a database sequence to be created, so you'll need to ensure that your database supports sequences and that the sequence is created before running your (JPA) application.

Comment: I have used sequence before and it created a separate id table. I copied your code and it also creates a separate "my_sequence" table with the id's. Both auto, sequence, and table does it, only identity doesn't.

Comment: I'm sorry. Usually I just use @Id and @GeneratedValue(), but I don't know how to have that start at a certain number.

Comment: Thank you for your answer anyway. I don't think it's possible to create a starting point when using the identity type.